# In Zeppelin, how can I change the value of parameters of form zeppelin.x.y

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

In particular, how can I change the value of *zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace*?

An error message gives the following comment:

> cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'X' '.' in expression specification; line 64 pos 10
>   set zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace = true to see full stacktrace

But how, exactly, do I set *zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace* to true? I've tried various config options such as adding an XML definition in *zeppelin-site.xml*, adding additional Java options via *zeppelin-env.sh*, etc. with no difference being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the not-very-obvious *interpreter.json* file, also in Zeppelin's *conf* directory. Simply find this entry:

> "zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace": "false"

and change it to

> "zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace": "true"

Restart Zeppelin and you will get the full stack traces with SQL errors.